# Incremental count from scanner input

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a function which is count batteries charging cycles/number, by scanning battery bar-code.
This is how I believe it should be done:

1. Each scanner input should be focused in a single "input data" cell or always active text box
2. The data is compared with a range of battery serial numbers in separate sheet.
3. If correctly matched against the input, the corresponding product counter should be incremented by one (if no match show alert "no matching serial)"
4. The input cell/text box should be focused and cleared to receive new data from the scanner input.

I'm using the following script, however `Call IncrementCycleCount(Target.Value)` is giving stack space error.

```
Const SCANNER_INPUT_CELL As String = "A2"
Const PRODUCT_WORKSHEET As String = "Batteries"
Const PRODUCT_COUNT_COLUMN As Integer = 2
 
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target = Range(SCANNER_INPUT_CELL) Then
        Call IncrementCycleCount(Target.Value)
        Target.Value = ""
        Target.Select
    End If
End Sub

Sub IncrementCycleCount(productID As String)
    Dim productList As Variant
    productList = Sheets(PRODUCT_WORKSHEET).UsedRange.Columns(1)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(productList)
        If productList(i, 1) = productID Then
            Sheets(PRODUCT_WORKSHEET).Cells(i, 2) = Sheets(PRODUCT_WORKSHEET).Cells(i, 2) + 1
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the Increment routine within a `Worksheet_Change`-Event. The routine changes data in the sheet and that again triggers a `Worksheet_Change`-Event, which calls the Increment routine and so on (until there is no more space on the Stack)

Put the statement `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the top of your event routine to prevent triggering new events and `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end of the routine to re-enable them:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Goto Change_End   ' Ensure that events are enables in any case
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target = Range(SCANNER_INPUT_CELL) Then
        Call IncrementCycleCount(Target.Value)
        Target.Value = ""
        Target.Select
    End If
Change_End:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick response, however you suggested solution giving the same error, I assume that the issue is in function IncrementCycleCount(Target.Value). Any ideas?

Comment: If you get an Stack Overflow Error, it is most likely you have an issue with recursion. There is no recursion beside the one I described. If the problem persist, try do debug the code to see what is going on. Set a breakpoint to the top of `IncrementCycleCount` and step thru the code with F8 until everything is done. Should jump back to the event routine and finish execution

Comment: @Al Smile  When somebody answer your question, we here tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for something similar will know that the code/suggestion works.

Comment: @Al Smile I would also suggest to create a boolean variable `boolFound` in the `IncrementCycleCount` `Sub` and make it `True` when a match has been found. If finally (after iteration) it is still `False', an alert/message ("no matching serial") can be sent...

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Const ScannerInputCell As String = "A2"
Const ProductWorksheet As String = "Batteries"
Const ProductCountColumn As Long = 2
 
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cel As Range
    Set cel = Range(ScannerInputCell)
    If Target = cel And cel.Value <> "" Then
        IncrementCycleCount cel.Value
        cel.Value = ""
        ' Not sure I like the following.
        Me.Activate ' To avoid error if run when another sheet is active.
        cel.Select
    End If
End Sub

Sub IncrementCycleCount(productID As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ProductWorksheet)
    Dim ProductList As Variant
    ProductList = ws.UsedRange.Columns(1)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(ProductList)
        If ProductList(i, 1) = productID Then
            ws.Cells(i, ProductCountColumn).Value _
              = ws.Cells(i, ProductCountColumn).Value + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    If i > UBound(ProductList) Then
        MsgBox "Product not found. Nothing done.", vbExclamation, "Fail"
    Else
        'MsgBox "Incremented the count of Product '" & productID & "'.", _
               vbInformation, "Success"
    End If
End Sub
```